# Overlay JS Video player for onclick() action

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, video

I am using a different video player that is supplied by a new CDN and a bunch of my users are upset because the mouse doesn't dissappear after 5 seconds of inaction, and they can't click anywhere to pause. I have been working with the player code and have a link that works to pause it:

```
<a onclick="videoPlayer.pause()" href="#">pause</a>
```

But I don't know how to do an overlay on the player. It needs to take up the top 90% of the player leaving the lower portion for video controls, then of course it will have to be different if it is full screen than if it is windowed.

Should I be using a  or a transparant GIF stretched over the player using CSS to position it?

Here is the code to run it, sorry but it is domain restricted so you can't actually play the video.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://admin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js"></script>
<object id="myExperience3619894642001" class="BrightcoveExperience">
  <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
  <param name="width" value="720" />
  <param name="height" value="480" />
  <param name="playerID" value="3617955641001" />
  <param name="playerKey" value="AQ~~,AAADSjjR4TE~,zW9NS0ZIOkOMdyn7JfUbJFmsqynLvYD8" />
  <param name="isVid" value="true" />
  <param name="isUI" value="true" />
  <param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true" />
  <param name="includeAPI" value="true" />
  <param name="templateLoadHandler" value="onTemplateLoad" />
  <param name="templateReadyHandler" value="onTemplateReady" />
  <param name="@videoPlayer" value="3619894642001" />
</object>
<script type="text/javascript">brightcove.createExperiences();
</script>
 <script type="text/JavaScript">
var player,
APIModules,
videoPlayer;

function onTemplateLoad(experienceID){
player = brightcove.api.getExperience(experienceID);
APIModules = brightcove.api.modules.APIModules;
}

function onTemplateReady(evt){
videoPlayer = player.getModule(APIModules.VIDEO_PLAYER);
videoPlayer.play();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not use a transparent GIF. Just use an empty HTML element like a `<div>` right before your player with whatever size you'd like with a negative bottom margin so that the video player will be placed behind the `<div>`. Here's an example if your video player is 480 pixels wide by 320 pixels high.

```
<div
    style="width: 480px; height: 288px; margin-bottom: -288px;"
    onclick="videoPlayer.pause()"
></div>
<object id="myExperience3619894642001" class="BrightcoveExperience">
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
    <param name="width" value="720" />
    <param name="height" value="480" />
    <param name="playerID" value="3617955641001" />
    <param name="playerKey" value="AQ~~,AAADSjjR4TE~,zW9NS0ZIOkOMdyn7JfUbJFmsqynLvYD8" />
    <param name="isVid" value="true" />
    <param name="isUI" value="true" />
    <param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true" />
    <param name="includeAPI" value="true" />
    <param name="templateLoadHandler" value="onTemplateLoad" />
    <param name="templateReadyHandler" value="onTemplateReady" />
    <param name="@videoPlayer" value="3619894642001" />
</object>
```